# how to run application even it is closed Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

how can i make an alarm application in Blackberry?

this means i have a time picker where user selects time, i then save that time and show a dialog when the system time matches with that time.

i have used `RealtimeClockListener` and the method `clockUpdated()` will give me time at every minute.  now when i closed the app that method is also closed

i want to execute that method if the app is closed or not

```java
public void clockUpdated() 
{
    int hour = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    //System.out.println("----"+Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.AM_PM));
    String am = ""+Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.AM_PM); 
}
```

Comment: Please don't open multiple user accounts on stack overflow for posting questions.  If you want to change your username, you can do that at any time.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use an alternate entry point and start a background application on device startup for listening to the RealTimeClockListener event. Use persistence to store and share the alarm time data.

See [Running in the Background Part 1](http://devblog.blackberry.com/2010/06/super-apps-java-series-running-in-the-background-part-1/) and [Part 2](http://devblog.blackberry.com/2010/06/running-in-the-background-part-2/) and [Creating an Always-On Experience](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/23567/Always_on_1380986_11.jsp) for more details.

Comment: hi, i'm new to BB so plz can u give simple example for alternate entry point and start a background application.

Comment: @Achin please learn to search  on google, you will find lots of examples.